# Any alternatives to Eclipse?

Tags: linux, eclipse, ide

I'm a long-term Linux developer, and I've been using Eclipse to do all my coding for years. It's got decent syntax highlighting for a range of languages, good project management, top-notch integrated VCS support, and its Java support is superb.

Unfortunately it's also huge, rather clunky, and has a number of bad habits ranging from files disappearing irrevocably if you accidentally undo in the project view after creating a file, to mysterious lockups where it will sit and think at 100% CPU for a minute, to an extremely clumsy package manager that seems to become more and more fragile the more stuff you install with it. So I'm looking for suggestions to an alternative to Eclipse that I can try.

There are, however, some provisos.

- There are two main styles of IDE. There's the Eclipse style, where a project is a directory; moving files in the project moves the files in the directory, so the project view can be treated as a file manager. And then there's the Visual Studio style, where the project is an abstract thing that does not necessarily match the layout on disk, and a project can contain files from multiple directories and moving files in the project doesn't touch the disk. This latter style I cannot stand, as it simply doesn't match the way I work. Unfortunately most Linux IDEs I've found work like Visual Studio. e.g. qtcreator, netbeans, monodevelop, etc.
- I *must* be able to create a raw, unmanaged project, where the IDE doesn't try to build stuff, debug stuff, or touch the files in any way other than just editing them and managing them. This is because most of my stuff tends to get built from the command line. For example, Code::Blocks, which otherwise looks excellent, insists on all projects having a managed build system with build configurations etc, and won't take no for an answer, even if said build system is totally irrelevant to what I want to do. Integrated build systems are all very well but if I can't just point the IDE at a directory full of files and edit them, I'm afraid it's useless to me.

The languages I work in are C, C++, Java, Lua, shell script, Vala, and a myriad of other things, so something with decently robust syntax highlighting would be nice.

I realise that I'm being quite picky, but IDEs are a very personal thing, and, well, that's how I work. I don't dislike Eclipse enough to warrant changing my workflow, but I would like to know if there's something better out there that I can use with the same workflow...

Comment: What is the point of an IDE that doesn't build, debug, or touch the files? How is that a step up from an editor with syntax highlighting and a built in file browser?

Comment: Because I want to be able to combine managed build projects (such as Java apps, where it really makes sense) with unmanaged build projects (such as combined C/Lua/Makefile based projects) in a single application using the same workflow.

Comment: In netbeans you can modify the ant build script to get the functionality you need.

Answer (score 14):

I'm not really a very experienced programmer, I only have about 3 years of experience, but during those three years I have become completely disappointed with every IDE that I used.

I tried Visual Studio, Eclipse, NetBeans, IntelliJ IDEA (that was the most horrible of them, probably), Qt Creator (this one was the nicest, for Qt projects). All of them were too slow, clunky, too "intrusive", had a lot of features I didn't even need and using them was a real pain. So here is what I did.

I uninstalled all those IDE's, installed the good old gvim text editor, downloaded a nice color scheme for it, installed a good font for programmers (terminus), installed a few nice vim plugins, learned the VIM commands, learned how to use my tools (GNU make, g++, cvs, git etc.) and lived happily ever after.

The advantage of Vim is that it's lightweight, does not hog up your system's resources, does not tell you what to do, yet it is powerful enough to be one of the best text editors out there.

However, if you find Vim hard to grok, I suggest that you try [Geany](http://geany.org), a lightweight text editor for programmers. Also, I have recetly checked out Code::Blocks and it seems close enough to be good. It's not good for Java development, though, but for C++ it's decent. So, you know, pick your poison :)

Comment: I've actually been using vim for years (and even have the vim keybindings plugin for Eclipse). The problem I have is that I do actually like guis, and for complex/rarely used tasks I do like nice menus and dialogues, and alas gvim doesn't cut it there. (Plus decent Java support requires running a headless Eclipse in the background...) But it does appear to have come on a long way since I last looked at it, so I'll have another go. Geany looks great, and is very much what I'm looking for, but when I tried it it was rather crashy (on a stock Ubuntu system).

Comment: Geany probably got a lot more stable since the last time you used it. I used it for a brief period of time and it didn't crash on me or anything.

Comment: +1 for saying that all IDEs are just to great dissapointment. Right not I only have to test QTCreator (And I'm not using QT at all), then I really have ruled them all out. Installing gVim as of writing this, just has to. I have seen emacs and thoose editors like fraks from the past century, but I haven't actually tested them...

Comment: +1 for suggesting Geany. One of the few IDEs I've found where one can just walk into a mostly unmanaged project and have the IDE be polite enough to not step on your toes.

Comment: Suggesting VIM or Geany to avoid Eclipse's memory consumption is like suggesting a razor scooter to avoid a car's gas consumption. You're not wrong, but that's also probably not a good solution for most people.

Answer (score 4):

How about [JEdit](http://www.jedit.org/)?

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend [Intellij Idea](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/). As of about a year ago they've got a free Community Edition.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Linux why not use xemacs (http://www.xemacs.org/)

To get an idea how to set it up for various languages you can look at this:
http://www.xemacs.org/Documentation/packages/html/prog-modes.html

Then for Java, you can look at http://jdee.sourceforge.net/

Emacs is very flexible, so you can get it to work as you desire, but, it will require more effort on your part that using a standard IDE, such as Eclipse.

Comment: Unfortunately as a long-term vim user I am contractually obliged to ignore your request. But it is a good choice.

Comment: Pick GNU Emacs over XEmacs, in short because it is more actively developed and has a greater number of features. If you're still wondering why people tend to prefer GNU Emacs, give this a skim: http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2008/04/xemacs-is-dead-long-live-xemacs.html

Answer (score 0):

When I don't want to wait for Eclipse to load I just use gedit - it's fast and has syntax highlighting.

You can open the sidebar to jump between open files or use the file browser and the bottom panel has a terminal to make in. If you use the External Tools Manager you can add custom scripts to be run by any shortcut key combination.